# Who is a true Brahmin?

Tags: puranas, dharma-shastras, brahmins, varna, bhavishya-purana

What do the Puranas say about moral decay in all castes?

Here is a link from Kamakoti org

https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part3/chap6.htm

What are the quotes of proper behaviours of sections of society?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering the main question.

It is rare to be a Brahmin by birth. Brahmins are supposed to be just
short of enlightenment. They must overcome all desires.

**Brahmana-hood is rare**

> The soul obtains human body after passing through series of births. O
> bird, in human body too, **his birth as a Brahmana is rare event**.

**Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XIX**

> Maheshwara said, ‘..**Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
> learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
> upon one the regenerate status. Verily, the conduct is the only
> ground. All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of
> conduct.** A Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as
> possessed of the status of a Brahmana. The status of a Brahma, O
> auspicious lady [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my
> opinion. He, indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma
> exists – that condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no
> stain attached to it. of human beings in four orders dependent on
> birth is only for purposes of classification. The boon giving Brahma,
> when he created all creatures, himself said that the distribution of
> human beings in four orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of
> classification.'

**Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII**

**Ways to become a Brahmana**

> Sage Pulastya said,"..by vows, by investiture of the sacred, by fasts,
> by rites, and by Mantras, one becometh a Brahmana."

**Mahabharata Aranya Parva LXXXIII**

> Only he who has purified himself by means of Gayatri Japa can be
> called a pure Brahmin. ….

**Shiva Purana, Vidyesvarasamhita, 15.18**

**Vyasa’s view of a Brahmana**

> Vyasa said, ‘Him the gods know for a Brahmana who is freed from
> attachments of every kind, who is observant of penances, who lives
> like space which while holding everything is yet unattached to
> anything, who has nothing which he calls his own, who leads a life of
> solitude, and whose is the tranquility of soul. The gods know him for
> a Brahmana whose life is for the practice of righteousness, whose
> righteousness is for the good of them that wait dutifully upon him,
> and whose days and nights exist only for the acquisition of merit. The
> gods know him for a Brahmana who is freed from desire, who never
> exerts himself for doing such acts as are done by worldly men, who
> never bends his head unto any one, who never flatters another, and who
> is free from attachments of every kind.’

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCXLV**

> Vyasa said, ‘Even this is the behavior of a Brahmana possessed of
> vision. He that hath studied all the Vedas, having waited dutifully on
> his preceptor and observed the vow of Brahmacharya, he that knows all
> the Richs, Yajus, and Samans, is not a regenerate person. One that
> behaves towards all creatures as if one is their kinsman, and one that
> is acquainted with Brahma, is said to be conversant with all the
> Vedas. One that is divested of desire (being contented with knowledge
> of the Soul), never dies. It is by such a behavior and such a frame of
> mind that one becomes a truly regenerate person. Having performed only
> various kinds of religious rites and diverse sacrifices completed with
> gift of Dakshina, one does not acquire the status of a Brahmana if he
> is devoid of compassion and hath not given up desire. When one ceases
> to fear all creatures and when all creatures cease to fear one, when
> one never desires for anything nor cherishes aversion for anything,
> then he is said to attain to the status of Brahma. When one abstains
> from injuring all creatures in thought, speech, and act, then he is
> said to acquire the status of Brahma. There is only one kind of
> bondage in this world, viz., the bondage of desire, and no other. One
> that is freed from the bondage of desire attains to the status of
> Brahma.’

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCLI**

Comment: It is clear from Pradip Gangopadhyay's answer that the traits and practices  described lead to freedom from passions and mind is freed to look deeply inwards. Acquire Brahmagyan, and so attain with some good actions granted status of Brahmin.

Answer (score 1):

I am just answering the main part of the question viz *"Who is a true Brahmana.?"*

According to the "[VajraSuchika Upanishad"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrasuchi_Upanishad).:

> तर्हि को वा ब्रह्मणो नाम । यः कश्चिदात्मानमद्वितीयं जातिगुणक्रियाहीनं षडूर्मिषड्भावेत्यादिसर्वदोषरहितं सत्यज्ञानानन्दानन्तस्वरूपं स्वयं निर्विकल्पमशेषकल्पाधारमशेषभूतान्तर्यामित्वेन वर्तमानमन्तर्यहिश्चाकाशवदनुस्यूतमखण्डानन्दस्वभावमप्रमेयं अनुभवैकवेद्यमपरोक्षतया भासमानं करतळामलकवत्साक्षादपरोक्षीकृत्य कृतार्थतया कामरागादिदोषरहितः शमदमादिसम्पन्नो भाव मात्सर्य तृष्णा आशा मोहादिरहितो दम्भाहङ्कारदिभिरसंस्पृष्टचेता वर्तत एवमुक्तलक्षणो यः स एव ब्राह्मणेति शृतिस्मृतीतिहासपुराणाभ्यामभिप्रायः अन्यथा हि ब्राह्मणत्वसिद्धिर्नास्त्येव । सच्चिदानान्दमात्मानमद्वितीयं ब्रह्म भावयेदित्युपनिषत् ॥९॥
>
> Who indeed then is brAhmaNa ? Whoever he may be, he who has directly realised his AtmA and who is directly cognizant, like the myrobalan in his palm, of his AtmA, that is without a second, that is devoid of class and actions, that is free from the faults of faults of the six stains (hunger, thirst, grief, confusion, old age, and death) and the six changes (birth, existence etc), that is of the nature of truth, knowledge, bliss and eternity, that is without any change in itself, that is the substratum of all the kalpas, that exists penetrating all things that pervades everything within and without as AkAsh, that is of nature of undivided bliss, that cannot be reasoned about and that is known only by direct cognition . He who by the reason of having obtained his wishes is devoid of the faults of thirst after worldly objects and passions, who is the possessor of the qualifications beginning with sAma (dama, uparati, titikShA, samadhana, sraddha), who is free from emotion, malice, thirst after worldly objects, desire, delusion, etc., whose mind is untouched by pride, egoism, etc., who possesses all these qualities and means- he only is the brAhmaNa. Such is the opinion of the veda, the smritis, the itihAsa, and the purANa-s . Otherwise one cannot obtain the status of a brahmaNa . One should meditate on his Atma as sachchidAnanda, and the non-dual brahman . Yea, one should meditate on his Atma as the sachchidAnanda brahman . Such is the upaniShad. ||9||.

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: Vajrasuchika attr. to Sankara, does not give caste by birth.

Comment: It's 36th in Muktika Upanishad Canon. And yes as mentioned in the above verse the self realisation and the above mentioned qualities are said to be the definition of a Brahmana there. As many rishis from other castes had became brahmana.

Comment: Temple priest mostly Brahmin caste. Kerala and TN training non-brahmin priests.Some non-brahmans are ritwij.  Those who still believe in ritual believe that the purohit should be Brahmin. A Brahmin by birth aged around 40 could still be vegetarian, from a family that practiced ritual purity and all the samskars. Women are also performing rites. My rituals are performed by the temple priest. Being a Brahmin in mental state is quite another meaning. And Brahmins not by birth, who acquire so called brahmagyan and merit are not accepted by traditional families for marriage alliance, generally.

Comment: My answer is totally scriptural based many people can think that castes are based on this so called birth but they were not but now its hereditary. Viswamitra, Valmiki, etc were good examples of people from different birth became a brahman. Yes, people might prefer it but its not the whole scenario.

Comment: The amount of austerities Vishwamitra had to undergo to become a brahmana was insane. I don’t think all the brahmanas that existed at that time put in that much effort. (Perhaps due to past actions)

Comment: To get brahma gyan and to become self realised the efforts are necessary the tapasya is also necessary. Valmiki as Ratnakar Dashyu started from Mara before reaching Rama.